# Summing up a row(where I am checking if the value is greater than -1% and lesser than 1%)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to check whether the value in the cell is greater than -1% and lesser than 1%.

Which I have done this way: C4>-1% *C4 < 1%

Then I want to sum up the number of cells that satisfy this condition within the same column.

For one cell, I do it this way: SUM(C4>-1% *C4 < 1%) but not sure how to extend it to the whole column.

Need some guidance..

Answer (score 1):

For fast workaround i would sugest you to put on the collumn for example D following formula:
=IF(C4>-1% *C4 < 1%;1;0)

Then sum all ones on this column.
But for sure there is easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
=COUNTIFS(C4:C9;">-1%";C4:C9;"<1%")

It should work correctly and is simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for checking if `C4 > 1%` and `C4 < 1%` does not work correctly. It works when it's evaluated initially, but does not update if the value in `C4` changes. Use `AND` function for this:

```
=AND(C4>-1%; C4<1%)
```

To count the number of cells which satisfy this condition, you could use a temporary column with formula:

```
=IF(AND(C4>-1%; C4<1%);1;0)
```

It will set the value in the cell to 1 if the value in C-column satisfies the condition, and to 0 otherwise. Then sum up the column:

```
=SUM(C1:C4)
```

This seems to be the easiest way to do it. Later you can hide the temporary column.
Another solution that comes to my mind is to write a small Visual Basic script but it does not look as a good option since the scripts are usually blocked unless they are signed with trusted certificate.